# A while loop is causing some graphical glitches

Tags: processing

I was just messing around with the while loop, testing it vs the for loop, when this graphical glitch occurred. This happens on an inconsistent basis, so I do refresh it to get results, but occasionally the screen will be split into horizontal lines, each with their different color. Why is this occurring?

```
int i = 0;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}
void draw() {
  while(i < 1) {
    background(random(255),random(255),random(255));
  }
  println("yes");
}

void mousePressed() {
  i += 1;
}
```

Comment: I would expect having a long running (potentially infinite) loop in the drawing function to cause the program to freeze up. Are you sure your even want the loop? It doesn't seem to be doing anything useful.

Comment: Execution never gets to the main event loop for the `mousePressed` event handler to fire. You have an infinite loop. The observed effect is curious (I see it too), but I don't think that it is worth much time in understanding it (which might require drilling down into the details of just when draw actually renders). My guess is that it has a background painting thread. While that thread is executing (which is during the first 3 or 4 passes through the `while` loop), it is responsive to changes in `background()`, but once it has done its initial painting it queues the remaining changes.